# Can you do video streaming in blackberry via http?

Tags: blackberry, video-streaming

Is there a way to do video streaming using an http url in a bb app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  A good place to start is the [multimedia development guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Playing_media_in_BB_device_app_739576_11.jsp).